# jQuery: Index of element ignoring selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to index sections of my site, but I'm running into an issue where jquery index() will index more then the selector I pass to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/8pDCM/1/

Using 'section' or even '.test' the index will start at 2.

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<section class="test"></section>
<section class="test"></section>
<section class="test"></section>
<section class="test"></section>
<section class="test"></section>
```

Comment: [It seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/yXK54/). Or maybe your question isn't clear enough.

Comment: @dystroy -- Post the answer, using `index('.test')` to target the correct elements. OP is just using `.index()`, so the start is actually the first div (to clear things up)

Comment: Perhaps I'm just using index incorrectly, but I would assume If I pass a selector of '.test' or 'section' my index would start 0 from the top. But index starts at 2 because it is including any div's I position at the top.

I updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/8pDCM/3/

Comment: I appreciate the help. On another note though... If you see my example now. When I scroll up my index changes to +1.

http://jsfiddle.net/8pDCM/4/

Comment: @hyperdrive That's just how waypoint work. It comes back to zero in this other example : http://jsfiddle.net/HTEnM/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the selector like this :

```
$(this).index('.test')
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/yXK54/)